# Pandas, how to merge columns into 1 where all the values are added together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

If I were to have a dataframe with the information (as shown above in the picture) where..

Row 1 held strings and Row 2 held numerical values

How would I merge all the columns in 1 column?

Using the picture as an example, the desired outcome in this case would be

[image]

Where the first row has been merged into single string character and row 2 has had all its values added together to give a result, in this case 78

Answer (score 0):

df['year'] = df.sum(axis=1)

For your second question, you state what the situation is, but you don't state what your desired outcome is.

edit: I assume that the "y" is constant. For the second row, if you just want one row, you can do df.loc[1].sum(). If you want that in a dataframe, you can do new_df = pd.DataFrame([['y'],[df.loc[1].sum()]]). If you want more than one row, you can do new_df = pd.DataFrame([['y']+[[df.loc[row].sum()] for row in range(1,df.shape[0]]])

Comment: 'I wish to merge all the columns into just 1 column, where all the numbers are totalled up' - e.g. in this case, if we used the picture above, the outcome would be 78

Comment: If you have a problem with my answer, you're going to have to be more explicit what it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum all elements in a row, you can simply say
`df.iloc[row_num].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are reading from a structured file format like csv, you could do something like this. I tried to answer the second part of your initial question as well.

`skip-rows` is a collection so it can obviously hold more than one row marked for skipping.

```
##ignore the repeating column-header rows by telling pandas which to skip when reading the file
df = pandas.read_csv('C:\\test.csv', skiprows=[16])
##create a new dataframe where you aggregate the columns into one value, Y
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=df.sum(axis=1), columns=["Y"])
```